# How SVN can tell you which files to add

Tags: php, svn, batch-file

I have a lot of modified files in my working-copy.

- How can I tell which files are new (don't exist in SVN), and how can those be added?
- If I delete a file in my working copy, how can I also delete it in SVN?

I use Windows and would like a DOS or PHP solution.

Comment: I tried to clean up the grammar and punctuation. Let me know if anything got lost in translation (or just roll-back the edit).

Comment: Thank you , i hope that will help me :D

Answer (score 1):

`svn status` will tell you what files aren't currently in your repository, what will be merged, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate to the folder under version control and run

```
svn status
```

A list of Added (A next to them), Deleted (D), Modified Files (M) and completely new (?) should be listed.

Do not delete outside of SVN, use SVN to delete the files by running

```
svn delete "filename"
```

If you don't when you update they will just keep coming back.

Full command list:

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/edguide/chapter03.html

Comment: Yes , i use that way to manage my files , but if you have Folder A and you have A/B svn status will work as you said. in my case , i will have A/B/C/D and if you go make svn status in D Folder , he will say D is not a worky copy folder

Comment: That means it isn't in your SVN repo yet, you need to Add the files/folders and then commit:

    svn add D